# ServletContext parameters: are they per instance or per server?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I have a tomcat server running a webapp. In the webapp's startup, I'm setting few context parameters using an implemented class for `interface ServletContextListener`. The parameter that I am initializing here are a couple of connection objects for a database running on a different machine.

The doubt that i have is whether the connection objects that I created here are one for each instance (since tomcat creates one instance per client request), or one for the entire webapp itself?.

If it is one per webapp, then can the server handle large simultaneous requests (in the order of thousand request per second) to perform the CRUD operations on the database?.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ServletContext` is created one per webApp. The server reads the web.xml file from the web app and creates a `ServletContext` based on the configuration you provide on web.xml. Once created it is shared between the components of the web app. If you have multiple webapp installed on your server, you will have multiple `ServletContext` - each for the web app.

For reference please have a look [here](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/ServletContext.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

A webapp has only one instance of ServletContext and the atributes in ServletContext are application scoped.

Regarding you database connection, it's better to use connection pooling (DataSource) instead of adding Connection objects as attributes in ServletContext.

Not sure if you mean this but the requests are handled by Servlets and not ServletContext.

Comment: Well, what i meant was with only one Connection object for the entire WebApp (which is not recommended), will the server be able to handle large number of requests simultaneously given that every instance of the client request has to use the same Connection object. I think I got my answer and now I have some huge amount of changes to make regarding the Connection objects. I read else where as well, that context params are not meant for 'heavy' objects like these. Only Constants are recommended.

Comment: It depends on your definition of large 100, 500, 10000 and keep in mind the performance. But as you yourself said it's not recommended

Answer (score 0):

If your setting an attribute on the `ServletContext` the attribute will be scoped for the entire application.

From the [Java EE 7 Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf?AuthParam=1382519225_179c1da5fcc7e2930b051a019a556818):

> There is one instance object of the ServletContext interface
>   associated with each Web application deployed into a container.

Answer (score 0):

only one ServletContext is loaded irrespective of the number of requests made.

This is even the advantage of servlets over CGI.

Hope it helps.